# How to distibute Word VBA macros to multipe Word docs?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a pretty sophisticated set of macros that add power to a Word doc. Within my company, the macros have proliferated to dozens of instances of the Word doc. Every now and then I improve or repair the macros, but it's painful to distribute the fixes to the dozens of instances of existing Word files. What should I be doing to simplify the distribution?

Can I write a macro to import macros? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion of macros in a Word document is both a blessing, and a curse: Simple distribution, but difficult to maintain.

Besides distribution in a document, you have two basic strategies for providing macros, both involve having the macros *in a template* (dotm file). When you do this, not only macros but also Ribbon customizations and keyboard shortcuts in the template are available. This reduces the number of storage files you have to maintain.

1. The template is linked to specific document(s) via the "attached template" property. Macros in an attached template are available only to documents linked to that template. A template is automatically linked to any document created from it using File/New. A template can be attached after-the-fact

   - in the UI: by selecting the template from Developer tab/Document template/Attach. (By default Normal.dotm is the attached template.)
   - through the object model using `ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "File path and name.dotm"`

   The template can be stored in the individual user's "Templates" file (in Windows 7 by default that would be something like `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`) or in a Shared templates location on a network. In this way it is available via File/New. (It can be stored anywhere else, as well, but then won't appear in File/New.)
2. The template is loaded as an add-in. This is most appropriate for functionality to be used in "all" documents, not just a specific document type.

   - Save the template in the user's Word/Startup folder if Word should load the template automatically (on Windows 7 the default installation path is something like `C:\Users\[unser name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP`)
   - A template add-in can also be loaded by the user explicitly via the Document Templates button mentioned above, using the "Add" button in the "Global templates and add-ins" section of the dialog box.

Theoretically, it is possible to use macros to edit macros. This involves introducing a security risk on the computer(s) where it's done (because this is how macro viruses are propagated). And the object model for doing so is very poorly documented and not very sophisticated (IOW it's not easy to write the code).

- You need to manually check the option "Trust access to vba project object model" in File/Options/Trust Center/Trust Center settings/Macro settings.
- You need to add a reference in your code project to "Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" in the VBA Editor's Tools/References

A third possibility is to back-up/export/save your code modules to plain text files using the VBA Editor's File/Export File command. Then use the File/Import File command to bring the code into the other document(s) / template(s). (Note: you first need to delete any code modules of the same name that already exist.) FWIW importing code from a file is also available in the VBA Extensibility object model.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I'm going to try teaching the Word doc to attach a template that's stored on the network, and I'm going to tinker with importing code modules programmatically. One of the modules I would want to update/import is a UserForm which contains both the graphical Object and the accompanying Code. Do you have any suggestions on how to import the Code of a UserForm without touching the Object of that Userform?

Comment: Tricky. You can edit the code in Notepad, but you can't import only the code. You'd have to export the entirety, remove the entirety, edit the code, then import both. The problem is you can't have two objects with the same name. But this kind of thing belongs in a new question :-)

Comment: BTW don't forget that on Stack Overflow the correct way to "thank" is to activate the checkmark next to the "Answer" as well as upvote :-)